# Google Cloud Stackdriver Monitoring - Compute Engine Disk Space

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloud, google-compute-engine, stackdriver

I am trying to add an alert and dashboard in Stackdriver Monitoring for our Google Cloud servers to monitor Disk Space (Volume).

I have managed to create the alert but am not getting any notifications even though I've set the threshold to 5%.

I can't seem to find an option at all in the Dashboard for Volume or Disk Space?

The server I am testing is running Windows 2012 R" and i have downloaded and installed the agent from - https://repo.stackdriver.com/windows/StackdriverMonitoring-GCM-46.exe

Comment: Do you have external IP with your VM instance? For instances without external IP addresses, you must enable [Private Google Access](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/configure-private-google-access) to allow the Monitoring agent to send metrics. "Disk utilization" (agent.googleapis.com/disk/percent_used) metric is a readily available [agent metric](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/metrics_agent#agent-disk). You can search typing "Disk utilization" at the metric field not "Volume" or "Disk Space".

Comment: The problem with "Disk utilization" is that it shows both free and used space, i have got round this by hiding half the results, but it's not ideal and no use at all for alerts.

Answer (score 0):

@David At the moment this feature is not available. While  setting up monitoring of disk volume is under investigation within cloud engineering team, I created this  [feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/111564620) on your behalf. You can track this thread to post any further comments or check the updates regarding this feature request.

Comment: Excellent Thank You